# (WPF) How can a separator be added between items in an ItemsControl - Bug Fixing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found solution on this site(How can I input separator between items in an ItemsControl([click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511227/how-can-a-separator-be-added-between-items-in-an-itemscontrol)) And found bug=((( 
Here is it:

[image]

It hapens when I trying to resize ItemsControl(I've set property "HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" to "Disable") Any ideas How should I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not easy,but I realized what shall I do to fix this bug. My idea is to use custom Convertor, but I haven't any clever thoughts How to send ConverterParameter into convertor. But I've found solution.
Here is my convertor:

```
public class SeparatorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private Visibility _visible;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var element = (TextBlock) value;
        element.Loaded += ElementLoaded;
        return _visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null; //not needed
    }
    private static void ElementLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as TextBlock;
        var parentItemsControl = element.FindParent(x => x is ItemsControl) as ItemsControl;
        var parentPanel = element.FindParent(x => x is Panel) as Panel;

        if (parentItemsControl == null || element == null || parentPanel== null)
            return;

        var itemText = parentPanel.FindName("MyTextBlock") as TextBlock;
        var collection = parentItemsControl.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<string>;

        if (itemText == null || collection == null)
            return;

        var list = collection.ToList();
        if (list.IndexOf(itemText.Text) == list.Count() - 1) // Can be incorrect because we can have two same items
           element.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Find parent function:

```
public static DependencyObject FindParent(this DependencyObject element, Func<DependencyObject, bool> filter)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            if (filter(parent))
            {
                return parent;
            }

            return FindParent(parent, filter);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Here is my XAML code:

```
  <Coverters:SeparatorConverter x:Key="SeparatorVisibilityConverter">
    </Coverters:SeparatorConverter>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Value, IsAsync=False}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockInListViewItem}"  TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="commaTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockInListViewItem}" Text=", " Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            Converter={StaticResource SeparatorVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Ok. Any way, If you have another idea how to fix this bug, you could post your answer here=)