# Distinct item template for first and last item in a ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate

I need to style the first and last items of a list view differently. To achieve that, I started working on a solution based on that answer: [Use different template for last item in a WPF itemscontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767097/use-different-template-for-last-item-in-a-wpf-itemscontrol/7767131#7767131)

Basically, I have a custom ItemsTemplateSelector that decide on the template to apply based on the item's index in the list view items (code below).

It works properly except that when the list gets updated (an item is added or removed), the templates do not get selected again (for instance, initially, the SingleItemTemplate gets selected because there is a single item. When I add an item to the list, that first item's template does not get switched to FirstItemTemplate). How to force template selection for all items?

```
public class FirstLastTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector 
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FirstItemTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate LastItemTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SingleItemTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ListView lv = VisualTreeHelperEx.FindParentOfType<ListView>(container);
        if (lv != null)
        {
            if (lv.Items.Count == 1)
            {
                return SingleItemTemplate;
            }

            int i = lv.Items.IndexOf(item);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                return FirstItemTemplate;
            }
            else if (i == lv.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                return LastItemTemplate;
            }
        }
        return DefaultTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As an alternative approach, I would suggest binding the `AlternationCount` of your `ItemsControl` to the number of items in your collection (e.g. the `Count` property). This will then assign to each container in your `ItemsControl` a unique `AlternationIndex` (0, 1, 2, ... Count-1). See here for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount.aspx

Once each container has a unique `AlternationIndex` you can use a `DataTrigger` in your container `Style`  to set the `ItemTemplate` based off of the index. This could be done using a `MultiBinding` with a converter that returns `True` if the index is equal the count, `False` otherwise. Of course you could also build a selector around this approach as well. With the exception of the converter, this approach is nice since it is a XAML only solution.

An example using a `ListBox`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Collections:ArrayList x:Key="MyCollection">
                <System:String>Item One</System:String>
                <System:String>Item Two</System:String>
                <System:String>Item Three</System:String>
            </Collections:ArrayList>

            <l:MyAlternationEqualityConverter x:Key="MyAlternationEqualityConverter" />

            <Style x:Key="MyListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyAlternationEqualityConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}" Path="Items.Count" />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <!-- Could set the ItemTemplate instead -->
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection}}"
                 AlternationCount="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Items.Count}"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyListBoxItemStyle}" />
    </Grid>
```

Where the converter might look something like:

```
class MyAlternationEqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length == 2 &&
            values[0] is int && values[1] is int)
        {
            return Equals((int) values[0], (int) values[1] + 1);
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I am wondering why you haven't compared using Datatrigger's Binding to ItemsCount and Value to AlternationCount? Is it because ItemCount is not a dependency property and it will throw error? Or is there any other reason? Because I see its going to be a boolean equal to comparision and why do we need a converter

Comment: @ramb00 I gave it a try and got: "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'DataTrigger'".  It seems Value isn't a dependencyProp.