# ListBox and ApplicationBar: last element padding

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a `ListBox` and `ApplicationBar` with `Opacity=.5`. I want that `ListBox` items are under the `ApplicationBar`.
Like figure:

[image]

But when I scrolled to end of list then last element of `ListBox` is under the `ApplicationBar`.

[image]

I want that last element is over `ApplicationBar`.

[image]

Can I add padding for a last element of the `ListBox` (`LongListSelector`)? How can solved this issue?

**UPDATE**

```
    <ListBox Name="MyListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                              {RelativeSource Self},
                                              Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}"
                             Value="True">
                            <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Padding" Value="0,0,0,72"/>
                        </ec:DataTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Red" 
                                Width="400"
                                Height="120"
                                Margin="15">                            
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>              
        </ListBox>
```

**UPDATE 2**

My problem can be easily solved by using `LongListSelector`. Just add empty `ListFooterTemplate` with Height = `ApplicationBar` height.

Comment: Have you tried applying padding/margin to `ListBox` itself?

Comment: yeah, if add to ListBox margin = 0,0,0,72 then all ListBox elements are above AppBar. But I need to only the last element was above the ApplicationBar.

Comment: What about padding to listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: Didn't see the update to the original question. The below remains for additional detail.

This solution is for Windows Phone 8 only (although you could use the LongListSelector from the Windows Phone Toolkit if you are targeting 7.1/5).

I'd replace the ListBox with the LongListSelector from the SDK

```
<Grid>
    <controls:LongListSelector ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Item}" ListFooterTemplate="{StaticResource Footer}" />
</Grid>
```

and for the templates add

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Item">
       <StackPanel Background="Red" 
                   Width="400"
                   Height="120"
                   Margin="15">                            
       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Footer">
        <Border Height="72" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `use converter to check if it's last item in listbox` and in case yes, set `padding to desired value via DataTrigger`.

Check my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131197/632337) for converter code. Just for sake of completeness of this answer i will post that converter code here:

```
public class IsLastItemInContainerConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                         object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
       DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)value;
       ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

       return ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item)
               == ic.Items.Count - 1;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                             object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                                  {RelativeSource Self},
                      Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: I try this, but I have a "System.NullReferenceException" in Converter line  "return ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item)==ic.Items.Count - 1;" ic = null :(

Comment: Can check with debugger attached if `ic` was null?

Comment: I checked it, I updated my post and add the xaml, I did everything right in the ListBox?

Comment: Code seems right. I have one question though - Why have you use interaction triggers? Why not to use DataTrigger directly under Style.Triggers?

Comment: What was the value passed to Converter. Was `item` is of type ListBoxItem in converter?

Comment: Windows Phone doesn't support style triggers. Oh, the value in converter has Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.DataTrigger type.

Comment: That's an issue then. I am not much a Windows Phone guy, so somehow you have to get to ListBoxItem to get it work. May be RealtiveSource with AncestorType set to ListBoxItem.

Comment: Try this in XAML - `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}`.

Comment: RelativeSource has only Self and TemplatedParent modes. I will try other options, thank you very much!

Comment: Ok. Would have offer my help in case i would have been a Windows Phone guy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simplest solution is to customize ItemsPanel property on ListBox:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,150"/> <!-- set margin to show some 'blank' space after last item -->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

But be aware that by default ListBox uses VirtualizedStackPanel as ItemsPanel. If you change it to StackPanel, it may bring some performance penalty. This is solution is suitable for lists with few items.