# DataTrigger for ItemsControl's ItemTemplate triggering on the last item in the list

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol

I Have an ItemsControl with a defined ItemTemplate. 
The ItemTemplate contains an image.
The Image has a style trigger to set the image.

What binding can I use to trigger a different image to be displayed if the item is the last in the list?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125764/change-style-of-last-item-in-listbox

Answer (score 3):

While the simplest approach for this is still probably to add an indicator field at the VM / collection level and refer to that property in the `Trigger`, there are some alternatives too.

One such could be to use the `AlternationCount` of the `ItemsControl`. This approach will make sure you're last item's special style is retained when changes are made to the source collection like when adding/removing/ sorting and sorts.

- In the `ItemsControl` set `AlternationCount="{Binding Items.Count}"` (`Items` is the collection being bound to)
- As for the trigger in `ItemTemplate` to detect the last item, it's a bit more complicated.

xaml:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
  <DataTrigger.Binding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
      <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType=ContentPresenter}" />
      <Binding Path="ItemsSource.Count"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType=ItemsControl}" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </DataTrigger.Binding>
  <!-- Change the following setter to what you need for new image -->
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="Tomato" />
</DataTrigger>
```

and the converter used:

```
internal class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    bool result;
    try {
      result = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]) == System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1]) - 1;
    } catch (Exception) {
      result = false;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```