# Replace element inside a DataTemplate

Tags: windows-phone-8, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I have a LongListSelector with a ItemTemplate like this:

```
<LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>

          Here I have a lot of elements that are always the same.
          .
          .
          .
          and one that varies

       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>     
</LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

I know how to use this [TemplateSelector](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/08/06/multiple-item-templates-in-windows-phone.aspx) class to change all the content inside the ItemTemplate depending o the item type.

My question is, how can use the template selector to change only the one item that varies so I dont need to repeat the whole lot of other elements.

I have tried using a `ContentControl` and `ContentPresenter` inside de `StackPanel` with no success

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to create a data trigger in your XAML to check whether each item is the one you're looking for.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125764/change-style-of-last-item-in-listbox) is relevant enough to get you on the right track. It'll end up looking something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Styling for elements that are NOT the last item -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource LastItemConverter}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
             </DataTrigger>
            <!-- Styling for elements that are the last item -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource LastItemConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
             </DataTrigger>
```

The Converter looks something like this - depending on what UI element you're binding.

```
public class IsLastItemInContainerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)value;
        TabControl tc = (TabControl)TabControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);


        // Return true for the first and last element 
        // (so they are similarly styled compared to other elements).
        if (tc.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) == tc.Items.Count - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (tc.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I dont want to style one specific item of the list. What I want is to reuse most of the DataTemplate except for one element. It like a DataTemplate inside a DataTemplate.