# Winrt - Specific ItemTemplate on last item of ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have this list view on a windows store app project

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}"  IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <Grid Width="280" Height="50" Margin="85,0,0,0">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RadioButton GroupName="meetingFiles" Content="TESTE" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"></RadioButton>
                                            <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                                            <Grid x:Name="whiteLine" Grid.Row="1" Width="270" Height="1" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
```

i want that my last item on the listview dont show the grid named whiteLine
how can i do that? or is it impossible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use different template for last item in a WPF itemscontrol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767097/use-different-template-for-last-item-in-a-wpf-itemscontrol)

Comment: Thats WPF, im working on winrt, i dont think it has  <DataTemplate.Triggers>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
<ListView ItemTemplateSelector="..."/>
```

Or binding the `Grid's Visibility` would do the trick.  But you would need some type of flag variable in your Model such that you can use that to determine if it is the last one in the list.

I used the above solution to alternate the background color of each item in the ListView, with my Model containing a RowID as well.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution would be to add a [Listview.footer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.footer.aspx) as so:

```
<ListView>
     <!-- Your Listview ItemTemplate /-->
     <ListView.Footer>
           <Grid Width="280" Height="50" Margin="85,0,0,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5" />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RadioButton GroupName="meetingFiles" Content="TESTE" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"></RadioButton>
           <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
     </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

This isn't really changing the last item, it is adding an element that is always at the bottom of the ListView, and looks the same as your items. This will give the user the impression that it is part of the listview, and you will keep your code simple.

Comment: If you could provide an example or other explanation, your answer would be a lot better.

Comment: I've just added more details and an example

Comment: Nicely done.  Unfortunately, I know nothing about XAML, so I can't upvote in good conscience, but your answer is a lot better now.