# Template in between items

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a collection of items and want to show it in a `ListView` as a List of comma separated values. How can I show a comma in between the values?

So far I've created a `ItemsPanelTemplate` with a `<VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>` as only child.

Obviously creating a `DataTemplate` which includes the comma would result in a tailing comma, where I don't want one.

Comment: How about `string.Join()` in your ViewModel?

Comment: Yes, if the items of the list were strings that would be an easy solution, however I want a more general solution. The comma-separation was just an illustration of the problem. And while I actually want a space-separation and the elements themselves are strings, I still don't want to join them, because they should have different colors and different hover-effects etc.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3351693/5380).

Answer (score 0):

Use this converter...

public class StringListConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public StringListConverter()
        {
            Separator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator + " ";
        }

```
    public string Separator { get; set; }



    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = "";
        if (value is IList<string> && targetType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
        {
            result = string.Join(Separator, (value as IList<string>).ToArray());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In XAML in the resources:

```
<rw:StringListConverter x:Key="StringListConverter"/>
```

then

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemList, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}"/>
```