# How can i know if a ListBoxItem is the last item inside a Wpf's ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

How can i know if a `ListBoxItem` is the last item of the collection (in the `ItemContainerStyle` or in the `ItemContainer`'s template) inside a Wpf's `ListBox`?

That question is because I need to know if an item is the last item to show it in other way. For example: suppose i want to show items separated by semi-colons but the last one: **a;b;c**

This is easy to do in html and ccs, using ccs selector. But, how can i do this in Wpf?

Comment: I have tried, but I just can't find a way to do this.

Comment: can you paste some xaml code?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511227/how-can-a-separator-be-added-between-items-in-an-itemscontrol).

Comment: Is there a NextData? In this case could be sovled my question.

Comment: Are all the items of the same type, or is the last one different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it seems to be [rather difficult to implement](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fbe80312-67aa-42ca-bd99-89b6d79e06ae/) an "Index" attached property to ListBoxItem to do the job right, I believe the easier way to accomplish that would be in MVVM.
You can add the logic necessary (a "IsLast" property, etc) to the entity type of the list and let the ViewModel deal with this, updating it when the collection is modified or replaced.

**EDIT**

After some attempts, I managed to implement indexing of ListBoxItems (and consequently checking for last) using a mix of attached properties and inheriting ListBox. Check it out:

```
public class IndexedListBox : System.Windows.Controls.ListBox
{
    public static int GetIndex(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(IndexProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIndex(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IndexProperty, value);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Keeps track of the index of a ListBoxItem
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Index", typeof(int), typeof(IndexedListBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));


    public static bool GetIsLast(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsLastProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsLast(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsLastProperty, value);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Informs if a ListBoxItem is the last in the collection.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLastProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsLast", typeof(bool), typeof(IndexedListBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));


    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Collections.IEnumerable oldValue, System.Collections.IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        // We capture the ItemsSourceChanged to check if the new one is modifiable, so we can react to its changes.

        var oldSource = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if(oldSource != null)
            oldSource.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;

        var newSource = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (newSource != null)
            newSource.CollectionChanged += ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;

        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    }

    void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ReindexItems();
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(System.Windows.DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        // We set the index and other related properties when generating a ItemContainer
        var index = this.Items.IndexOf(item); 
        SetIsLast(element, index == this.Items.Count - 1);
        SetIndex(element, index);

        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }

    private void ReindexItems()
    {
        // If the collection is modified, it may be necessary to reindex all ListBoxItems.
        foreach (var item in this.Items)
        {
            var itemContainer = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            if (itemContainer == null) continue;

            int index = this.Items.IndexOf(item);
            SetIsLast(itemContainer, index == this.Items.Count - 1);
            SetIndex(itemContainer, index);
        }
    }
}
```

To test it, we setup a simple ViewModel and an Item class:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private ObservableCollection<Item> items;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return this.items; }
        set
        {
            if (this.items != value)
            {
                this.items = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.InitItems(20);
    }

    public void InitItems(int count)
    {

        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { MyProperty = "Element" + i });
    }

}

public class Item
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.MyProperty;
    }
}
```

The view:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
        <Border x:Name="border">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding (local:IndexedListBox.Index), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding (local:IndexedListBox.IsLast), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (local:IndexedListBox.IsLast), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.949*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <local:IndexedListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate}"/>

    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Margin="8" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Margin="110,8,0,8" Click="Button_Click_1"  d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Margin="242,8,192,8" Click="Button_Click_2"  d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

In the view's code behind I put some logic to test the behavior of the solution when updating the collection:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get { return this.DataContext as ViewModel; } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.Items.Insert( 5, new Item() { MyProperty= "NewElement" });
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.Items.RemoveAt(5);
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.InitItems(new Random().Next(10,30));
    }
}
```

This solution can handle static lists and also ObservableCollections and adding, removing, inserting items to it. Hope you find it useful.

**EDIT**

Tested it with CollectionViews and it works just fine.

In the first test, I changed Sort/GroupDescriptions in the ListBox.Items. When one of them was changed, the ListBox recreates the containeirs, and then PrepareContainerForItemOverride hits. As it looks for the right index in the ListBox.Items itself, the order is updated correctly.

In the second I made the Items property in the ViewModel a ListCollectionView. In this case, when the descriptions were changed, the CollectionChanged was raised and the ListBox reacted as expected.

Comment: It is a complicated solution, but is seems to work. But, this works when the SortDescription changed? For example, when user sort items in the view changing the SortDescriptions.

Comment: Good point, I have not tested for that. If you are binding to a CollectionView, it shall work, as it implements INotifyCollectionChanged and probably raises a CollectionChanged when reordered. If not, we can try to listen to modifications to the ListBox.Items instead of the ItemsSource in the method OnItemsSourceChanged. I've got to take a look on that. In my first approach, I tried to listen only to the ItemContainerGenerator, but it did not work well, as apparently items are created on demand because of virtualization.