# Text separator between ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I'm trying to get the following from a ListView:

```
Text | Text | Text
```

I've already achieved the vertical orientation by the following

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/></ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Each part(Text) is a TextBlock bound to a string in MVVM. 
Preferably the lines between should just be regular vertical bars.

Any tips for achieving these vertical bars as specified??

Comment: What is your current problem? What is your current result and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Don't have a current result, as I can't think of a recursive way to have vertical lines as specified, without either starting with or ending with a vertical line

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a separator be added between items in an ItemsControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511227/how-can-a-separator-be-added-between-items-in-an-itemscontrol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [How can a separator be added between items in an ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511227/how-can-a-separator-be-added-between-items-in-an-itemscontrol), try this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="theListBox">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="seperator" Text=" | "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="seperator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have achieved to show separator in between two items, you can have a converter say `LastItemInContainerToVisibilityConverter` which will be binded to the visibility of separator making `separator collapsed for last item` and `visible for all other items`.

Assuming you have used `Rectangle` to show the seperation between items -

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
         <Rectangle Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                   Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem},
                                  Converter={StaticResource 
                                   LastItemInContainerToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Here goes your converter which will return if it's last item in collection -

```
public class LastItemInContainerToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
       DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)value;
       ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

       return (ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item)
            == ic.Items.Count - 1) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```