# ListView with horizontal wrapped arrangement of items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I want to layout items in a WPF listview in a similar manner to GridView in Windows store application. Items are grouped horizontally and each group panel lays out items horizontally warpped, something like this:

```
Group 1                 Group2                  Group3
Item1, Item2, Item3     Item1, Item2, Item3     Item1, Item2, Item3
Item4                   Item4                   Item4
```

I've tried working with StackPanel and WrapPanel but never get the result I mentioned above.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Group 1"/>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 1, "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 2, "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 3, "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 4"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Group 2"/>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 1, "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 2, "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 3, "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 4"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Width="auto">
        <TextBlock Text="Group 3"/>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 1, "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 2, "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 3, "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 4"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Instead of putting the items as TextBlocks (with hard coded commas), you would likely use an itemscontrol (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3351693/9732)).

Here is a sample screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes , i have done it, please follow below link:

http://amritverma88.blogspot.in/