# ItemsControl wrapping issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I did small custom ItemsControl to show some list as row of items. And it works almost perfectly.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock x:Name="delimiter" Text=";" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding LinkId}" />
       </WrapPanel>
       <DataTemplate.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="delimiter" Value="Collapsed"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

My problem is in delimiter: when ItemsConteol is wrapping to next row then delimiter char goes start of next row.

I understand where is the problem, but I don't know how to sove it.

[image: Result]

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You can actually use AlternationCount-based solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34138980/276994) (but you need to target last item, not first one)

Comment: @Vlad, thanks. Unfortunately, this method laso is not applyable for me: no delimiter between first and second elements. But I decide to avoid Triggers at all, in my task delimiter after last element is not a critical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple solution with `DataTemplateSelector`. It goes like this:

You define a selector, which distinguishes the last item.

```
class LastElementSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate NormalTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate LastTemplate { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return IsLast(container) ? LastTemplate : NormalTemplate;
    }

    bool IsLast(DependencyObject container)
    {
        var itemsControl = FindParentOrSelf<ItemsControl>(container);
        var idx = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);
        var count = itemsControl.Items.Count;
        return idx == count - 1;
    }

    T FindParentOrSelf<T>(DependencyObject from) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (var curr = from; curr != null; curr = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(curr))
            if (curr is T t)
                return t;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Having this, you can use different templates for normal and last items:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:LastElementSelector>
            <local:LastElementSelector.NormalTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/><!-- no space between runs
                        --><Run Text="; " Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:LastElementSelector.NormalTemplate>
            <local:LastElementSelector.LastTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:LastElementSelector.LastTemplate>
        </local:LastElementSelector>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ItemsControl>
```

Result:

[image: test run]

Answer (score 1):

Your delimiter goes in front in the next line because it is in front of the LinkId TextBox and both of them are bound together inside a WrapPanel. The whole WrapPanel flows to the next line.

The parent panel above the WrapPanels does not know and does not care about what is inside them.

[image: Example showing the approximate Layout]

By the way, I don't know if it was your intention, but in your code as it is written you generate a different WrapPanel for every item in your collection. As it stands, you have 20 WrapPanels in your testlist.

If, as you say, delimiter after the last is not a problem, this is a good enough solution:

```
    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}"
        >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                ></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    >
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding LinkId}"
                        ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="; "
                        ></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

If this is only for data displaying purposes, consider that those texboxes in line could very much be a single String inside of a TextBox. Maybe you could use a single formatted String and make the relevant parts into Links. This would move the string-delimiter part of the action to the ViewModel and would simplify a lot your XAML code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try put the delimiter *after* the text and hide the last `Run` element by settings its `Text` property to an empty string:

```
<ItemsControl AlternationCount="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Items.Count}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}" /><Run x:Name="delimiter" Text=";    "/>
            </TextBlock>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="delimiter" Value=""/>
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This should keep the delimiter and text on the same line.